# Confusion about definition of crystals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules, derived-algebraic-geometry, geometric-langlands, crystals

In the [notes by Lurie](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Egaitsgde/grad_2009/SeminarNotes/Nov17-19(Crystals).pdf) there seems to be *two* possible definition for crystals which both makes sense for arbitrary functors $X : \mathrm{CRing}_k \to \mathrm{Set}$. ($k$ here is a field. We probably need to restrict $\mathrm{CRing}_k$ to just the full subcategory $\mathrm{CRing}^{\mathrm{ft}}_k$ of finite type commutative algebras at some point.)

> Definition (infinitesimal groupoid). $X^{(2)}$ is defined as the fiber product of $X$ with itself over $X_{\mathrm{dR}}$. This is naturally a groupoid over $X$.

> Definition (Integrable connection). A crystal on $X$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$ equipped with equivariance with respect to $X^{(2)}$.

> Definition (de Rham space version). A crystal on $X$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf on $X_{\mathrm{dR}}$.

In the notes, it is mentioned that the "integrable connections" definition matches the "de Rham space" definition under the assumption that $X$ is a smooth scheme. Actually, I believe the argument only requires $X$ to be formally smooth in the sense that $X \to X_{\mathrm{dR}}$ to be a surjection of functors.

My question is: outside the assumption of formal smoothness on $X$, which definition is the "correct" one?

I'm quite confused because in the notes mentioned above, they seem to take the "integrable connection" definition as the basic one. However, in the [the paper by Gaitsgory and Rozenblyum](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2087) they seem to take the "de Rham space" definition as the basic one.